# Setting DataFrame columns from current columns' data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've stumbled upon intricate data and I want to present it totally differently.

Currently, my dataframe has a default index (numerated) and 3 labels: sequence (that stores sentences), labels (which is a list that contains 20 different strings) and scores which is again a list (length of 20) that corresponds to the labels list and the ith element in the scores list is the score of the ith element in the labels list.

The labels list is sorted via the scores list; if label j has the highest score in row i, then j would show up first in the labels list; but if another label has the highest score, it would show up first instead.. so essentially it's sorted by the scores list.

I want to paint a different picture: use the labels list as my new columns and as value, use the corresponding values via the scores list.

For example, if this is is how my current dataframe looks like:

```
d = {'sentence': ['Hello, my name is...', 'I enjoy reading books'], 'labels': [['Happy', 'Sad'],['Sad', 'Happy']],'score': [['0.9','0.1'],['0.8','0.2']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

I want to keep the first column which is the sentence, but then use the labels like the rest of the columns and fill it with the value of the corresponding scores.

An example output would be then:

```
new_format_d  = {'sentence': ['Hello, my name is...', 'I enjoy reading books'], 'Happy': ['0.9', '0.2'],'Sad': ['0.1','0.2']}
new_format_df = pd.DataFrame(data=new_format_df )
new_format_df
```

Is there an "easy" way to execute that?

Comment: Please give an output sample you want (based on your example).

Comment: Is the second row of in `labels` is `['Sad, Happy']` or `['Sad', 'Happy']`?

Comment: Added an output example.

Comment: @MohammadrezaRiahi - When trying the pivot method, I'm getting an error: "No numeric types to aggregate", I'm assuming this is because the numbers we see are type str. I can't seem to convert it via using .astype(int). Note that the scores are stored in a list; each sentence (row) has its own list with different scores. Any idea how can I convert it efficiently? To be clear - each score is actually a string type! '[0.9,0.1]' so i can't just use int on the entire thing cause it's a long string that contains '[', etc

Comment: You mean that the `score` has values like this: '[0.9,0.1]', '[0.8, 0.2]' ?

Comment: yeah but the main problem is not that tbh, it still gives me an error when i try to pivot, claiming that there's no numeric values to aggregate (I'm assuming cause the numeric values are within a list still)

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to solve it using a NumPy array hack:

First you convert the lists to np arrays:

```
df['labels'] = df['labels'].map(lambda x: np.array(x))
df['scores'] = df['scores'].map(lambda x: np.array(x))
```

Then, you loop over the labels and add each label, one at a time, and its corresponding scores using the boolean condition described below:

```
for label in df['labels'][0]:
    df[label] = df_text_20[['labels','scores']].apply(lambda x: x[1][x[0]==label][0], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to change your dictionary if you can. First find the indices of the `Happy` and `Sad` from `labels`:

```
happy_index = [internal_list.index('Happy') for internal_list in d['labels']]
sad_index = [internal_list.index('Sad') for internal_list in d['labels']]
```

Then add new keys name `Happy` and `Sad` to your dictionary:

```
d['Happy'] = [d['score'][cnt][index] for cnt, index in enumerate(happy_index)]
d['Sad'] = [d['score'][cnt][index] for cnt, index in enumerate(sad_index)]
```

Finally, delete your redundant keys and convert it to dataframe:

```
del d['labels']
del d['score']
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

    sentence               Happy  Sad
0   Hello, my name is...   0.9    0.1
1   I enjoy reading books  0.2    0.8
```

Comment: Thank you, though it would not present it in the same way I wanted to. I added an example output to make my question more clear. Thanks again.

Comment: the updated solution gives me the following error: unhashable type: 'list'. i tried using .pivot instead. didn't help either. thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I test in and then update my answer. But now, when I run my solution it does not work!! Your solution is interesting.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate the time and effort you've put into this. Cheers!